# What does かの日 mean?

Tags: words, meaning

In my Japanese Bible, I've seen several passages that use the phrase `かの日`.  Here are a couple.

> - ある人たちの習慣に倣【なら】って集会を怠【なまけ】ったりせず、むしろ励【はげ】まし合いましょう。**かの日**が近づいているのをあなたがたは知っているのですから、ますます励【はげ】まし合おうではありませんか。　－　ヘブライ人への手紙 / 10章 25節
> - **かの日**には、大勢の者がわたしに、『主よ、主よ、わたしたちは御名【み・な】によって預言【よ・げん】し、御名【み・な】によって悪霊【あく・りょう】を追い出し、御名【み・な】によって奇跡をいろいろ行ったではありませんか』と言うであろう。 　－　マタイによる福音書【ふく・いん・しょ】 / 7章 22節
> - **かの日**、主が来られるとき、主は御自分の聖なる者たちの間であがめられ、また、すべて信じる者たちの間でほめたたえられるのです。それは、あなたがたがわたしたちのもたらした証【あか】しを信じたからです。 　－　テサロニケの信徒への手紙二 / 1章 10節

I haven't been able to find the exact phrase in any dictionary.  The best I can theorize is that it is [`彼【か】の`](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%BD%BC%E3%81%AE), which is basically the same as `その` or `あの`.  So it would be something like "On that day..."

Is this correct?  If so, is it some literary term?  What advantage does it have over `その` or `あの`?  If not (correct), what is it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, 彼【か】の **isn't** basically the same as 其【そ】の, but it **is** basically the same as 彼【あ】の, except that it's older and no longer used as much.    In short, か became あ.

かの is preserved in some modern words and phrases:

- かの女【おんな】 became　かの女【じょ】 and stuck around (rather than becoming あの女【おんな】).  Of course, you usually see this written 彼女, with the genitive の left unwritten.
- かの有名な still comes up, I think as a set phrase (rather than あの有名な)

But mostly it's just an old form of あの.  So `かの日` means `あの日`, but it sounds older.

Comment: I thought the かの in かの女　was 彼?

Comment: @Ataraxia Indeed, so is the かの in the かの日 above! By the way, the kanji for both あの and かの is 彼の (hardly used in formal setting though).

Comment: かの日=the day you know
[岩波]{いわなみ}[国語]{こくご}[辞典]{じてん}[第]{だい}三[版]{ぱん} says かの means 「あの」③, and 「あの」③ is 今の[時点]{じてん}とは[離]{はな}れているが[相手]{あいて}も[知]{し}っている[事柄]{ことがら}に[関係]{かんけい}する[意]{い}を[表]{あらわ}す[語]{ご}
KJV's translation of Heb 10:25 is 'as ye see the day approaching. '