# What is the etymology behind 彼氏(彼) and 彼女 meaning boyfriend/girlfriend?

Tags: etymology

So according to [Can someone break down かのじょ and かれ for me?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/34534/can-someone-break-down-%e3%81%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%81%98%e3%82%87-and-%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8c-for-me/34536#34536) it seems that 彼 and 彼女 are words that only came to mean "he"/"she" due to the influence of the West. But I'd like to know a bit more about how those third person pronouns came to mean boyfriend/girlfriend. Some preliminary research indicates 徳川夢声 might be behind the reason for 彼氏 and 彼女, but if any additional light/specifics could be shed on the top that'd be great

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at these two in turn.

#### 彼氏【かれし】

According to Shogakukan's 国語大辞典【こくごだいじてん】 (KDJ) entry [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%BD%BC%E6%B0%8F-468384#E7.B2.BE.E9.81.B8.E7.89.88.20.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.9B.BD.E8.AA.9E.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E5.85.B8), 彼氏 initially meant just "that person", derived as 彼【かれ】 + honorific person suffix 氏【し】.  Apparently the honorific was used a bit ironically, and the term was actually intended as a slight pejorative.  If the entry is anything to go by, it appears in texts starting from 1929, in one of [徳川【とくがわ】無声【むせい】](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BE%B3%E5%B7%9D%E5%A4%A2%E5%A3%B0)'s works.

A bit later in 1934 in a piece by 永井【ながい】荷風【かふう】, we see usage in the sense of "boyfriend, male lover".  This appears to be a straightforward extension of the meaning "fellow, guy" in usage patterns like "she's got a *guy*, that's her *fellow*", where the "boyfriend" sense arises out of context.  Compare German usage, where *Mann* literally just means "man", but in the context of talking about a woman's relationships, it also means "husband".  (The English term *man* is also used the same way, albeit in a more informal speech register.)

I suspect that both terms were in common use before either publication appeared.

#### 彼女【かのじょ】

Here's the [KDJ entry link](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%BD%BC%E5%A5%B3-465534#E7.B2.BE.E9.81.B8.E7.89.88.20.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.9B.BD.E8.AA.9E.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E5.85.B8).  Use in the "she" sense as a female third-person pronoun shows up in 1885.

Then the "girlfriend, female lover" sense shows up later, and is recorded in the 1931 ウルトラモダン辞典【じてん】.  I don't see any usage examples from that time, but again, my hunch is that this too was an extension of the earlier "she" meaning: "he's got a *girl*".  Compare German usage, where *Frau* literally means "woman", but in the context of talking about a man's relationships, it also means "wife".

Once again, these meanings were probably around for some time before they were put to print.